# Given $a \le b < c < d$, show that $|a - d| > |b - c|$

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

This is for a real analysis class.

For real numbers $ a,b,c,d$, is it sufficient to state the following?

$$|a-d| = |a-b| + |b-c| + |c-d| > |b-c|$$

since $|c-d| > 0$.

How would I provide more detail to demonstrate that the equality holds?

Comment: $\left|a-d\right|=d-a$, $\left|a-b\right|=b-a$ and so on.

Comment: $d-a \gt c -a \gt c -b$

Comment: @zkutch The second inequality is not strict , but this in fact proofs the claim.

Comment: Thanks, @Peter. I know. I saw left side in OP title. I wanted to be sure that the questioner would read my comment (I sometimes check to see if someone is listening), and I would write a response, but that didn't happen. You are right anyway.

Comment: @zkutch Nice test. Unfortunately, the author failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a\leq b$

$\implies a-b\leq 0$

$\implies |a-b|\geq 0$

And, $c\lt d$

$\implies c-d\lt 0$

$\implies |c-d|\gt 0$

$\begin{align}\therefore &|a-b|+|c-d|\gt 0\\ & |b-c|+|a-b|+|c-d|\gt |b-c|\\ & |a-d|\gt |b-c|\end{align}$. **QED**

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$a<d~ ,b<c, ~d>c,~b≥a$$

Therefore,

$$|a-d|>|b-c|$$

$$\begin{align}&\implies d-a -(c-b)>0\\
&\implies d-a-c+b>0\\
&\implies(d-c)+(b-a)>0.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$|a-d|=d-a>0\,\, \text{ and }\,\,|b-c|=c-b>0$$
as well as $$ d-c>0\,\,\text{ and }\,\,b-a\geq 0$$
hence $$(d-c)+(b-a)>0\Longrightarrow d-a>c-b$$
as required.